# How do I use the JQuery Datepicker with a textbox input onclick

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How do I use the JQuery Datepicker with a textbox input onclick i do not want on focus and calender images

```
  $("#my_txtbox").datepicker({
 // options
 });
```

Comment: yes i want that but not showing me any option of that.

Comment: There's a check mark next to the answers to your questions that you can click when you deem an answer appropriately answered. Click it to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You need to download 2 JS files for that.
```

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/date.js
    http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js

Add these 2 files in page and Keep that text box in one class and using that class , u can do what u want.

```
Like this:
$(function()
{
     $('.date-pick').datePicker({clickInput:true}) 
}
);

<input id="datepicker" class="date-pick"/>
keep the classname as "date-pick".
```